# like and whereIn query doesn't show result as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this query still shows the result of the `like` query even if the item on the like query doesn't exist on the tag_id

```php
User::where('name', 'like', '%' . request()->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request()->search . '%')
                ->whereIn('tag_id', [1, 3])
                ->get()
```

how do I show the result that exists only in the tag_id ?

so for example, if the `like` query finds John but John is not in the `tag_id` of 1,3, it won't show the result of `like John`

Comment: hi, have you tried to dump your query and see how it looked like? also, which version is your laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with lavarel but it should work

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses), you can pass function query builder in a where clause.

It allow you to do a `OR` between your `like` conditions only, and a `AND` between this part and the `whereIn`

```
where (A or B) and C
```

```php
User::where(function($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request()->search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request()->search . '%');
                })
                ->whereIn('tag_id', [1, 3])
                ->get()
```

Comment: Please eplaine what you have done and why *it should work*